# angular datasource remove item

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular and I have a datasource for my table. I want to delete the item from datasource. please help me

```
empDataSource: EmpDataSource;
selection = new SelectionModel<Employee>(true, []);

 ngOnInit() {
this.empDataSource= new EmpDataSource(this.empList);
}

deleteEmp(){
   this.empDataSource= this.empDataSource.data.filter(row => row!=this.selection.select(row));
}
```

Here I am not able to find the "filter" option in datasource, Can some one please help any other way to delete item from datasource

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo here :

```
deleteEmp(){
   //this.empDataSource <!!!here!!!> = this.empDataSource.data.filter(row => row!=this.selection.select(row));
   this.empDataSource.data = this.empDataSource.data.filter(row => row!=this.selection.select(row));
}
```

Comment: it doesn't have filter option in data. filter is undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

simple just use ES6 filter arrow function

```
this.empDataSource.data = this.empDataSource.data.filter(
   row => !this.selection.selected.includes(row)
);
```